# is this a possible integration bug?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am find a discrepancy in evaluating an integral which has given me trouble all day. I have finally isolated where the problem is which I now frame:

I define the integral in terms of a delayed function such as:

```
FFex1[x_, X_, Y_, Z_, t_] := 
Integrate[((x - X) (t/Sqrt[
  t^2 + x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + 2 t Z + Z^2] + 
  Z (-(1/Sqrt[x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + Z^2]) + 1/
     Sqrt[t^2 + x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + 2 t Z + 
      Z^2])))/(x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + (y - Y)^2), y];
```

which when evaluated with

```
(FFex1[200, 10., 10., 174., 20] /. y -> 100.)
```

gives the output "0.0175145".

Now I define the same function but without the delay:

```
FFex2[x_, X_, Y_, Z_, t_] = 
Integrate[((x - X) (t/Sqrt[
  t^2 + x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + 2 t Z + Z^2] + 
  Z (-(1/Sqrt[x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + Z^2]) + 1/
     Sqrt[t^2 + x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + 2 t Z + 
      Z^2])))/(x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + (y - Y)^2), y];
```

which for

```
(FFex2[200, 10., 10., 174., 20] /. y -> 100.)
```

yeild "-3.12408". What gives? I am using Mathematica 9.

Comment: I think that the two functions that you gave are the same.

Comment: Please note that the [tag:bugs] tag is to be added only after ["community consensus"](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190/how-to-report-bugs).

Comment: (1) As an indefinite integral, shouldn't any two answers differ at most by a constant?  *Mathematica* leaves off the "+C", so often insisted on by calculus teachers.  So I don't see a problem with getting two different numbers.

Comment: (2) Using `Integrate` with approximate numeric coefficients is often unreliable, since quantities that might be exactly zero and cancel will appear to be only approximately zero and not cancel.  (Among other things.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your integral results vary by a constant of integration (see Possible Issues->Indefinite Integrals in the documentation for `Integrate`).

Observe

```
FFex1[x_, X_, Y_, Z_, t_] := 
  Integrate[((x - 
        X) (t/Sqrt[
          t^2 + x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + 2 t Z + Z^2] +
         Z (-(1/Sqrt[x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + Z^2]) + 
           1/Sqrt[t^2 + x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + 
              2 t Z + Z^2])))/(x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + (y - Y)^2), y];
FFex2[x_, X_, Y_, Z_, t_] = 
  Integrate[((x - 
        X) (t/Sqrt[
          t^2 + x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + 2 t Z + Z^2] +
         Z (-(1/Sqrt[x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + Z^2]) + 
           1/Sqrt[t^2 + x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + y^2 - 2 y Y + Y^2 + 
              2 t Z + Z^2])))/(x^2 - 2 x X + X^2 + (y - Y)^2), y];

Table[
  FFex1[200, 10., 10., 174., 20] - FFex2[200, 10., 10., 174., 20] /. y -> ic,
  {ic, 1, 20}]
```

gives

> ```
>  {-3.14159 + 0. I, -3.14159 + 0. I, -3.14159 + 0. I, -3.14159 + 
>   0. I, -3.14159 + 0. I, -3.14159 + 0. I, -3.14159 + 0. I, -3.14159 + 
>   0. I, -3.14159 + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 3.14159 + 0. I, 3.14159 + 0. I, 
>   3.14159 + 0. I, 3.14159 + 0. I, 3.14159 + 0. I, 3.14159 + 0. I, 
>   3.14159 + 0. I, 3.14159 + 0. I, 3.14159 + 0. I, 3.14159 + 0. I}
> ```

Comment: I think you're missing part of your `Table` code. (Also there's a misplaced comma.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good catches. Thank you.

Comment: oh I feel foolish now. Never had a problem like this before but I guess I don't use definite integration very often.